# What is the optimal way to store a string in a database?

Tags: mysql, string

I am trying to store a 9 character string in a database that I will query to find additional information related to it.

However, I want to store it as a number to make the querying process faster and more efficient.
The string would've been 10 bytes, translating each character to a 2 digit number would let me use the big int data type which uses 8 bytes...

That's a good improvement but I wanted to see if there was an even more efficient way to store that because a 9 character string seems like it should be using less space.

Comment: This reads like premature optimization. String and numbers are two different things, and the decision on which one to use should not be primarily based on storage impact, but on how you will use that data... which you did not really tell.

Comment: I will be using it only as a search field. So I need the searching process to be the most efficient possible in terms of space and in terms of time.

Comment: All 9-digit numbers can be represented using only 4 bytes. If the number range is below 2^32, or 4,294,967,296, mysql's unsigned integer type can store them all.

Comment: @Bohemian 4 byte integers can hold all positive 9 digit numbers. Moreover, I'm looking for a good conversion method from string to int that will save space and time. I am aware of what can store what.

Comment: Have you tried `convert(mycolumn to unsigned)`?

Comment: Store as a `[VAR]BINARY(9)` if indeed it doesn't have a character set, have it indexed, and you won't notice the difference compared to a `[BIG]INT` lookup.

Comment: Can you demonstrate that the benefit of speed will outweigh the overhead of conversion?

Comment: Please provide an example data of what are you trying to do. This over optimization may not make sense. Too much, too soon...